# Cannot launch simulated executable: no file found

Tags: xcode, ios-simulator, xctest, deriveddata

I'm running into an error when trying to run simulator:

Cannot launch simulated executable: no file found at /Users/currentUser/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/cbre360-gruwumfjqskyvobphvorjwmieiij/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/cbre360-Test.xctest

I've tried deleting derived data and cleaning the build folder but to no avail. Any idea how to solve this issue?